# How to reference a cell from another sheet?

Tags: excel, formula

I have to count the number of cells that are not empty in a range, so I must use the `COUNTA` function. The problem is, I want it to be dynamic.

**Steps:**

First, I have to retrieve the reference of a cell in D column, and the line correspond to the line in A column who contains a specific string. Let's assume that this string is "NRUTI_02".

So here is my code

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("NRUTI_02";A1:A65535;0);4)
```

It searchs for the string inside the range `A1:A65535`, and once it's found, it applies an offset to get the "D" column (4).
-> If "NRUTI_02" is in `A18`, the output will be `D18`.

If I change to another sheet (Sheet1), the code will be the following :

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0);4)
```

However, to use this formula inside `COUNTA`, I must use the `INDIRECT` formula. But if I put `INDIRECT` before my formula, it doesn't work.

How can I use my formula inside `COUTNA` function please ?

EDIT : My goal is to have something like `COUNTA('Sheet1!'D18:D65535)`

EDIT 2 : `COUNTA("Sheet1!D"&MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0):D65535)` isn't working

EDIT3 : Real example :
My string "NRUTI_02" is in A18. The beginning of my range would be D18, because I want to count on column D. The next empty cell in column D is D21. I want to count all cells (lines) in range D18:D21. So I'd like my range to be kind of dynamic : the first arg find automatically D18, and the last arg would take the output of the first arg until the end of column.

```
COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D;MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A:A;0)):INDEX(Sheet1!D18:D65535;MATCH(TRUE;ISBLANK(Sheet1!D18:D65535);0))) ;
```

EDIT4 : Here is what my Excel file looks like : [XLSX](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=fb6fe3734e5040f8aceb3f53656e29532174f550f0bb3f289f5743c0004972041108e9c84b309f397c54355d1ff18535d01cab91c1a2d186a48332c825d49410)

Answer (score 2):

Doable with `INDEX` instead of `ADDRESS`.

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH("NRUTI_02",Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,65535))
```

or even simpler:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH("NRUTI_02",Sheet1!A:A,0)):Sheet1!D65535)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Would it be possible to modify the range in order that the second index point on the next blank cell ? Like this :
COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D;MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A:A;0)):INDEX(Sheet1!D18:D65535;MATCH(TRUE;ISBLANK(Sheet1!D18:D65535);0))) ; where D18 would be the column D and 18 the line of the range beginning ??

Comment: I added an example, do you see what I'm trying to explain ? And thanks again for your help

Comment: You can use COUNTA on the entire column, or do you only want to count the first "block" of data? Meaning, do you have a several rows of data, and then blank row(s), and then more data?

Comment: Yes I have several rows of data, with the same pattern : blank row, more data, ...

Comment: Try this - enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter: `=COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D;MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A:A;0)):INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D;MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A:A;0)):Sheet1!D65535;MATCH(TRUE;ISBLANK(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D;MATCH("NRUTI_02";Sheet1!A:A;0)):Sheet1!D65535);0)))`.

Comment: It doesn't give me the right result, I uploaded my XLSX file in my original post hope this can help! For example, NRUTI_02 should give me 3, NRUTI_01 should give me 1 and NRUTI_03 should give me 5. Thanks for your help !

Comment: BTW - this would be much easier with a helper column and COUNTIF.